# Firewall-Iptables-Linux : how to force the same source port for all outgoing packets

Tags: linux, multithreading, sockets, iptables

I'am developing an application with tcl language composed by several processus.
each processus has to send a data using a socket (IP, Port) to an external IP address.
I should use only the port 5060 (as I'm simulating a SIP server).
The problem is that only one thread can use the port 5060 each time when using the socket (parallel threads using the same source port is then impossible) so I should resolve this.
I wonder if I can use linux iptables to change source port used by each thread when several threads are running simultaneously (each one on a different socket) ==>all transmitted packets from the machine are with the same source port 5060.

Any suggestion or information is welcome.
(I need a concrete example if the case)
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: IMHO this question as written is off-topic, but FWIW I don't think there's any reason why you shouldn't be able to have each thread use the same source port.

Answer (score 1):

Why can you not use this from multiple threads? Outgoing packets should not have any contention - this would only be an issue when binding to a port for incoming connections, which can only be done by a single thread - if this is the case, your application design is flawed in that only one thread should be accepting connections, and handing them off to workers.

To answer the question asked... This `iptables` rule should redirect all outgoing packets to a specific port.

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -j REDIRECT --to-port 5060
```

If you want to bind this to a specific interface

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -i eth0 -j REDIRECT --to-port 5060
```

Or only when talking to a specific destination

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -s www.xxx.yyy.zzz -j REDIRECT --to-port 5060
```